# Most viewed posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql

I am owner of a blog/website and I am using this code for tracking post views in site :

```
  function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

I want to fetch most viewed posts today, last week, last month to show in sidebar.

Is there any way to sort posts based on post views.

The post views is stored in a custom field post_views

please guide me.

Rias

Comment: There are some plugins for eg. "popular widget" which sort the most viewed posts... but i am not sure if they are able to display results on daily basis...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/super-useful-wordpress-hacks-and-snippets
You source? I made a widget that does just that, on this same code.
To sort:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args); //http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

//the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    //do your magic
endwhile;
```